# extract substring from string in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

For a shell script I am passing  table names as an argument.

```
Table=$1
```

The table name is `1234_abcd`, `2345_cde` and so on.

In the same script I have another argument called number

I want to extract the number from table like anything before the underscore and pass in the same script

Like

`Number=1234`

How can I achieve that in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code answer your question?

```
$ string="1234_abcd"
$ read num1<<<${string//[^0-9]/ }
$ echo "$num1"
1234
```

Comment: say if I have a string as 1234_abcd_9999 I want only 1234 as a result